# How to force Image Button dimensions

Tags: image, xaml, maui, imagebutton

I have an image button that I need to force to a small size (16 x 16 pixels).
My images are exactly 16x16 pixels with no whitespace surrounding them.
Leaving all heights and widths to auto, I get this:
[image]

I tried setting the height request and width request to 16 but it only scaled the image up to the size of the button. Putting even smaller numbers didn't make a difference.

```
<Grid ColumnSpacing="10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
    <Label x:Name="ListName" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>

    <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
        <ImageButton Clicked="OnMoveUp" Source="uparrow_16.png" 
                     Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                     HeightRequest="16" WidthRequest="16"/>
        <ImageButton Clicked="OnMoveDown" Source="downarrow_16.png" 
                     Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                     HeightRequest="16" WidthRequest="16"/>
        <ImageButton Clicked="OnRemove" Source="trashcan_16.png" 
                     Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                     HeightRequest="16" WidthRequest="16"/>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
    
    <VerticalStackLayout x:Name="Content" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

    </VerticalStackLayout>
</Grid>
```

[image]

I also tried messing with the height of the row but that only caused the images to get scaled weird and cut off parts of the images. (I removed the heightrequest and widthrequest attributes and it didn't make a difference)

```
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="16"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps try setting `Padding=0` ?

Comment: @StephenQuan I tried that but it makes no difference unfortunately. Margin="0" doesn't do anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested on my side and this actually the design on the MAUI Windows platform. You can not to change the `Imagebutton` height by using the grid height.
But you can use the `AbsoluteLayout` to change the item's height and position.

```
 <AbsoluteLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" >
            <ImageButton  Source="pic.png"
                     Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Center" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="36,0,16,16"
                     />
            <ImageButton Source="pic2.png"
                     Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Center" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="52,0,16,16"
                    />
            <ImageButton  Source="pic.png"
                     Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Center" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="20,0,16,16"
                    />
 </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: This does make the buttons the right size but for some reason it causes the images to get scaled up and then cut off like they did in the last image.

Comment: This depends on the platform. When I test it on the Android platform this issue will not happen. You can report it as an issue which occurred on the Windows platform on the GitHub.

Comment: Thank you. I decided to switch to WPF as I only needed to develop for Windows anyways. I'm having a much easier time on there so far.